# XML parsing with filtering

Tags: jquery, html, xml

My XML file looks like this -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <prj:Flow xmlns:prj="url1" xmlns:com="url2" xmlns:ns2="url3" xmlns:con="url4" xmlns:ns0="url5" xmlns:ns1="url6" xmlns:ns3="url7">
    <prj:str>
    <prj:layout comp="abcd">
      <prj:prop>
         <prj:property name="Hardik" value="5000"/>
      </prj:prop>
    <prj:look>
      <prj:lite name="bajaj">
      <prj:lite name="honda">
    </prj:look>
    </prj:layout>
<prj:layout comp="efgh">
      <prj:prop>
         <prj:property name="Vipul" value="6000"/>
      </prj:prop>
    <prj:look>
      <prj:lite name="yamaha">
      <prj:lite name="honda">
    </prj:look>
    </prj:layout>
    </prj:str>
    </prj:Flow>
```

I need to parse this XML such that I can retrieve the children of  based on the  comp value i.e if comp="abcd" then I should be displaying bajaj and honda in my html table. Today my parser is showing all the  attributes irrespective of the comp value being used to filter. Any help is highly appreciated.

My Parser -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'sample.xml',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
       var compname = $(xml).find("prj\\:layout,layout").attr('comp');
       if(compname == "abcd") {
          $(xml).find("prj\\:look, look").each(function() {
            var $entry = $(this);
            var pic = $entry.find("prj\\:lite,lite").each(function() {
              var name = $(this).attr('name');
              $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + name + '</td>').appendTo('#listnames');
        })
      })
    }
}  
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

The reason you get all the attributes is that your var compname declaration is not in a loop. Now you are asking: from all the layouts, give me an attribute called comp. Since .attr() will return the attribute of the first hit this will always return 'abcd'. So when you check for compname = "abcd" it is always true.

**A possible solution**

You could loop the layouts. Then within that loop check what the compname attribute for the current layout is. Then do a check if that matches your target compname. The rest of your code works fine.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'sample.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {

    //First find the layouts
    var layouts = $(xml).find("prj\\:layout,layout");

    //Loop through the layouts
    layouts.each(function(){

      //Get this layout comp attribute
      var compname = $(this).attr('comp');

      //check if the comp is our target comp
      if(compname == "abcd") {
        var $entry = $(this);

        //Loop the 'lite' elements
        var pic = $entry.find("prj\\:lite,lite").each(function() {
          var name = $(this).attr('name');

          //Log for testing (remove in production)
          console.log("found " + name);

          //Your magic
          $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + name + '</td>').appendTo('#listnames');

        })
      }
    })

  }  
})
```

**A more efficient solution**

You could also structure your selector in a way that you get the correct lite elements right away

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'sample.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {

    //Find the entries
    var $entries = $(xml).find("prj\\:layout[comp='abcd'] prj\\:lite");

    //Loop the entries
    $entries.each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('name');

      //Log for testing (remove in production)
      console.log("found " + name);

      //Your magic
      $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + name + '</td>').appendTo('#listnames');

    })

  }  
})
```

Comment: It displays bajaj,honda,yamaha and honda while I want it to display bajaj and honda only as I need <prj:lite> attributes under comp="abcd" .

Comment: Any responses on this one ? I am still a little clueless :(

Comment: Did you update your code as I suggested? If so, please show updated code

Comment: $(xml).find("prj\\:look, look").each(function() {
          var compname = $(xml).find("prj\\:layout,layout").attr('comp');
          if(compname == "abcd") {
            var $entry = $(this);
            var pic = $entry.find("prj\\:lite,lite").each(function() {  
              var name = $(this).attr('name');
              $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + name + '</td>').appendTo('#listnames');
              })
              }
            })

Comment: Hi rsihtahnikkaar I've updated the answer with a code sample.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much Jan Jouke Tjalsma. I have a better understanding about looping through XML schemas now.